# Running selenium test suites with Maven/Eclipse for dummies

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium

I have to test a web app using Selenium test cases/test suites that will run through Maven. I am new to it all. Can anyone outline the simple basic steps to run my first test successfully? I have everything installed (Eclipse, Maven, Selenium). Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed Maven Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Might help to see an active example and working integration between jUnit, eclipse, Maven and Selenium.

You can download a working project [here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/archive/master.zip)

or you can check it out from GitHub from [here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium).

If you read the readme on that project, it states that you can run the tests individually by right clicking the method names, and clicking Run As->jUnit tests or you can run the class suite.

Comment: Hello! Who has created this project? Is there anything special that I need to know in order to use it with my test cases?

Comment: It's a project designed to help people get started with Selenium Webdriver with Java.  Sounds like exactly what you need.  Anything special?  Don't think so.. i provided everything you need to get started in the readme.   It's a free version of the frameworks that i use for production style regression testing.

Comment: If you check out that project, there is a test that you can view called `SampleFunctionalTest` and you can see how validations and actions on the websites work :)  (see the test [here](https://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium/blob/master/src/tests/java/com/company/seleniumframework/functional/SampleFunctionalTest.java))